# How to avoid duplicate commits in Git when applying hotfixes using the develop branch Git flow development model?

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

We are using the `develop` branch development model in one of our projects.

```
o - - - A - o - o - o - o  master
| \   /
 \  o  hotfix1
  \   \
    o - B - o - o - o develop
```

In the above diagram a `hotfix1` is required and we apply (merge) it in both the `master` and the `develop` branch. This results in 2 different commit IDs A and X.

At a later point we need a new hotfix which again is applied in `master` resulting in commit C:

```
o - - - A  ...  A - - - C  master
| \   /           \   / 
 \  M  hotfix1       N  hotfix2
  \   \               \
    o - X - o - o - o - ?(A, N)? develop
```

But merging `hotfix2` into the `develop` branch, we get the following list of commits in the Merge Request (GitLab terminology):

```
N
A
```

This has several drawbacks:

- the code reviewer will see much more changes than in the commit N even if all these changed are already in `develop` (via commit X). This makes it more complicated to review.
- after a merge, in `develop` we see both X and the newly brought A (via merging of N). Like this we have the same changes and the same git commit messages (`git log`) in two different commits.

How can we avoid this duplication of commits in `master` and `develop`? We would like to continue using the `develop` branch model.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of merging the hotfix (branch) in develop, you can cherry-pick (`git cherry-pick <commitHash>`) the commit(s) containing the fixes, it would create the following:

```
o - - - A  ...  A - - - C  master
| \   /           \   / 
 \  M  hotfix1       N  hotfix2
  \   \
   o - X - o - o - o - N' develop
```

N' would have the same content as N, but not the same parents, therefore not the same hash, but also, not having the same parents means that in your merge request, A will not be present.

Comment: You could then never merge develop to master

Comment: why not? Master would then contain N and N', but that would not be an issue.

Comment: I think that at a later point in time, you cannot escape the duplicate commits when someone will merge master into develop. I like @jthill's answer which, if followed, solved probably most of the trouble by having commits applied only in the correct place and avoids unnecessary merges.

Comment: the commit `N` will be duplicated indeed (as `N'`), but that's fine. What it solves in that if you merge `N` in develop, all its parents (which are already in master) will end up as children of develop too, whereas if you cherry-pick it (effectively duplicate the commit), only this one will be in develop, the rest of master will not.

Answer (score 2):

This is why I advocate hotfixing bugs by branching from the commit that *introduced* the error. There's two parts to a hotfix: the code that should have been written in the first place, and what the current code would look like as a result.  When you only branch from a current tip, you only get the second part, which may not apply cleanly to other tips and might, as it does here, not be cleanly separable from unrelated work you don't want applied elsewhere.

The minimum clean-hotfix base is the merge base of all tips with the bug, to which that hotfix might ever need to be merged.  Anything past that merge base means your hotfix history includes other content you didn't want to merge yet anyway.

But for accountability and cleanliness, I think it's best to go back and find the commit that introduced the bug, branch from there, commit what should have been there, merge from the current merge base to resolve all common conflicts (keeping separation of the bugfix and integration work), then merge from that to each tip that needs hotfixing.

Comment: I like this concept!